# C- Basic syntax unexpected fail when forward declaring "warning: data definition has no type or storage class"

Tags: c, declaration, forward-declaration, statements, entry-point

I encounter some unexpected issues to compile a piece of code and after some time working on it, I think I need assistance. This trim down to a really small minimal exemple. I feel really lost because I am not a total beginner at C, and computer science and general, and for me, not only this should work but it also sound super basic.

```
#include <string.h>
char* tamere;
tamere=strdup("flute");
```

Nothing wierd. **strdup** return a pointer to **char**. **tamere** is declared as pointer to **char**. The compiler is free to allocate on the stack the place for **tamere** when he see the declaration. Then later, it set it to the result of **strdup** at definition on line after.

## Gcc output

But this basic piece of code fail to compile on my debian machine:

```
b.c:3:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 tamere=strdup("flute");
b.c:3:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘tamere’ [-Wimplicit-int]
b.c:3:1: error: conflicting types for ‘tamere’
b.c:2:7: note: previous declaration of ‘tamere’ was here
 char* tamere;
       ^~~~~~
b.c:3:8: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 tamere=strdup("flute");
        ^~~~~~
b.c:3:8: error: initializer element is not constant
```

So, the question is why? Why this C piece of code is not working. Why the raisonning about compiler seeing the declaration and being able to do is work is wrong? What is the easiest way around?

## Gcc version

```
gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Thanks for your help :)

Edit: The current answer explain what is happening. However one could imagine compilers to be a bit smarter, to replace

```
char* tamere;
tamere = "tata";
```

(not compiling) into:

```
  char* tamere = "tata";
```

A even smarter compiler (I tought compilers were smart enought to replace compile time knowed variable (such as 3*2) by there values, would even allow

```
char* tamere;
tamere=strdup("tata");
```

Because strdup("tata") could be replaced by "tata" (a heap "tata")

Any reason why this is not a thing, and if you want to separate static variable declaration and definition, you have to write a one time function to setup do the definition?

Comment: In the file scope you may use only declarations but not statements like this tamere=strdup("flute"); Instead you could use an initializer in the declaration char* tamere =strdup("flute");

Comment: You mean that outside function, anything is a declaration for the compiler, explaining why the first warning? What a surprise, I did not know that. Go ahead and answer.

Comment: I mean still if someone can explain why this limitation exist, that would be even nicer

Answer (score 3):

You may use only declarations in the file scope but not statements. It is functions that get the control and execute code in C. And the main entry point of a C program is the function `main`.

From the C Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner

The compiler tries to reinterpret this statement

```
tamere=strdup("flute");
```

as a declaration with the implied type specifier `int`. And as a result it resumes that the variable `tamere` was redeclared with a different type specifier.

```
b.c:3:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 tamere=strdup("flute");
b.c:3:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘tamere’ [-Wimplicit-int]
b.c:3:1: error: conflicting types for ‘tamere’
```

You could use the expression in the statement as an initializer in the declaration

```
char * tamere = strdup("flute");
```

But the compiler expects a constant expression as an initializer of a variable with the static storage duration. So it again will issue an error.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

So the only acceptable initialization can look like

```
char * tamere = "flute";
```

Otherwise you have to set the value of the pointer in some function for example in main.

Pay attention to that `strdup` is not a standard C function.

Comment: You are right about the compiler warning, howewer the last line you said dont compile for the reasons explained by the first answer. Which for me is weird. Because strdup("flute") should be computable at compile time. I thought compiler would replace compile time known variable (such as 2*3) by there simple constant value (6)

Comment: @ninjaconcombre I updated my post. Variables with teh static storage duration as your declaration shall be initialized by constant expressions.

Comment: @ninjaconcombre Dynamic allocation at compile-time doesn't make any sense. Unlike for example integer constant expressions, that _are_ resolved at compile-time.

Comment: Any deterministic function called with only constant argurments could be resolved by compiler at compile time instead of calling the function at run-time . I thought that it would does that. Probably I was wrong. Maybe there is compile flag to do that?

Comment: `Any deterministic function called with only constant argurments could be resolved by compiler at compile time instead of calling the function at run-time.` How can you return a pointer to heap at compile time? `strdup` is not deterministic - it can fail.

Comment: @KamilCuk Ha yes you right, everything involving malloc would not be possible :(.  I thought the compiler could replace the pointer to heap to pointer to a constant memory. But in case of strdup the result must be writable

Answer (score 2):

You cannot execute code outside functions in C. You can only initialize variables declared there to *constant expressions*. A function call is never a constant expression since it is resolved in run-time.

The historical reason why C is like this, is probably efficiency. All plain variables at file scope have static storage duration and must be initialized before main() is called. Initialized objects through `.data` segment and non (zero) initialized objects through `.bss` segment. This variable initialization already consumes start-up overhead.

If you would in addition to that also execute functions, the start-up time of the program would become even slower. For example, this is a known performance problem in the C++ language, where objects with static storage duration have their constructors called at start-up.

Furthermore, the function `strdup` isn't standard C and might not exist inside `string.h`. If you compile the code in strict C mode, this function might turn unavailable since conforming compilers aren't allowed to declare non-standard functions inside standard headers such as `string.h`. I'd advise to use malloc + strcpy/memcpy instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, howewer, for me nothing  would prohibit a compiler to allow to forward declare knowed a compil time variable (such as strdup(constant)). Even worst, the following code dont compile for the same reason:char* tamere;tamere="tata";
If compiler was just a bit smarter, everything he could resolve at compile time could be forward declarable out of scope, just by transforming the forward declaration in initialization. A reason what they dont do that?

Comment: @ninjaconcombre Initialization and assignment are different technical concepts. Simply write `char* tamere="tata"`. I don't understand what you mean with "could be forward declarable out of scope, just by transforming the forward declaration in initialization".

Comment: I dont understand why compiler dont have this feature, to just check that affectation result is known at compile time. Unstead of prohibiting totally out of function forward declaration. If result is known at compile time,the compiler could transform char* tamere; tamere=result in char* tamere = result. Now I need to define a function that I will call only once to set a variable to a compile time known variable, which feel weird for me.

Comment: I mean obviously the real code is way more complex, it's about some macros that define magic enum which separate the declaration and definition in different macros, in order to be able to include the declaration more than in one module.

Comment: @ninjaconcombre A lot of the C language is cumbersome and many rationales (if they exist) about why things are the way they are, may be dated to the 1970s. Overall though, "the spirit of C" is to remain efficient and close to the hardware. You just have to learn all the quirks and live with them. On the bright side, every such quirk is well-known and well-tried, which is never the case when it comes to new language features.